# CosmosDB Graph: How to update a value of property of vertex having multiple values using gremlin?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin

Suppose my query is :

```
g.addV('employee').property('id', 'john').property('country', 'USA').property('country', 'India')
```

which adds property country with two values i.e USA and India.

```
[
 {
  "id":"john",
  "label":"employee",
  "type":"vertex",
  "properties":{
                "country":[
                          {
                           "id":"5dc2aaf6-cb11-4d4a-a2ce-e5fe79d28c80",
                           "value":"USA"
                          },
                          {
                           "id":"fcf4baf6-b4d5-45a3-a4ba-83a859806aef",
                           "value":"India"
                          }
                          ]
                }
 }
]
```

Now I want to change one of the existing values. For example **'India'** to **'China'**.

What will be query for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a single query it's just that:

```
g.V().has('id', 'john').
  sideEffect(properties('country').hasValue('India').drop()).
  property(list, 'country', 'China')
```

Answer (score 2):

We could drop the **'India'** value firstly and then add the **'China'**. I test it with following query on my side, it works correctly.

```
g.V().has('id', 'john').properties('country').hasValue('India').drop()
g.V().has('id', 'john').property(list, 'country', 'China')
```

Comment: Yes, This is definitely an option. But I was looking for a single query so that I don't have to use two different queries for updating a property. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

g.V().has('employee','id', 'john').property('country', 'China')

Comment: This query will replace the value of property 'country' with 'China', not the individual value 'India'.  

Result will be:
[{"id":"john","label":"employee","type":"vertex","properties":{"country":[{"id":"3fe29e5e-34b5-481d-bdeb-672415cc2d6d","value":"China"}]}}]  

Both values 'USA' and 'India' will be replaced.

Comment: I did not realize that. I thought because you didn't use `list` in your original query that it would not have created a `list` and instead the latter value `India` would have overwritten the previous value `USA`.  But there it is in the reference.  I find that behavior to be non-intuitive - works one way after `addV()` but differently otherwise.